# Как создать ПРОСТОЙ словарь с поиском?

Tags: python

К примеру: **Пользователь вводит в поисковик желаемое слово, к примеру, "Файл"
После этого происходит поиск по библиотеке, пользователю открывается (или выполняет)
сообщение, в котором говорится значение этого слова.**

Искал гугл, но, там не получается, там нужно через сам код писать, типа print(имя группы),
а мне нужно, чтобы не писать это в коде, а через терминал или панель ввести слово

Answer (score 2):

Используйте словарь, как уже было сказано в другом ответе:

```
word_dict = {
    'файл': "Файл (англ. file) — именованная область данных на носителе информации, используемая как базовый объект взаимодействия с данными в операционных системах.",
    'сокет': 'Со́кет (англ. socket — разъём) — название программного интерфейса для обеспечения обмена данными между процессами.',
}

word = input('Введите слово: ').lower()
if word in word_dict:
    print(word_dict[word])
else:
    print('Слово не найдено:', word)
```

Ввод-вывод:

```
Введите слово: файл
Файл (англ. file) — именованная область данных на носителе информации, используемая как базовый объект взаимодействия с данными в операционных системах.
```

Comment: Благодарю!!  Очень сильно помогли!